# Does JMeter have Request Time vs Response Time graph?

Tags: testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

I need to know exact response time for particular request sent. Is there any plugins similar to my requirement where i can see both the request and response time together.

From my research, **Response Time vs Thread** was similar to my requirement but can  we consider number of threads as number of request in JMeter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing that "request time", JMeter measures:

- request start time
- response time which also includes

  - connect time
  - and latency

The closest thing is [`Transaction Throughput vs Threads` chart](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionThroughputVsThreads/)  which is available as a part of **KPI vs KPI Graphs** bundle, can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)